# iOS: Subclass singleton in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a framework where I have a singleton class, let's say Singleton. This class is used by other classes in the framework.

In the app project I want to subclass this singleton class, e.g. AppSingleton: Singleton. Is it possible? What is the right solution?

Comment: You never subclass a singleton. Because if you subclass it then it's not a singleton anymore.

Comment: You're right. Thank you.

Comment: Thats not right. Subclassing does not mean it wont be a singleton anymore. It just means that another singleton object will now exist in the app which takes behavioural similarities from it.

Comment: Could you elaborate, what exactly is the use case? Most of the things can be achieved by extending the singleton class.

Answer (score 0):

I provide a solution but it may be a little hacky.

```
Class A {
  open class var shared: A {
    return A.privateShared
  }
  private static let privateShared = A()
}

Class B {
  open class var shared: B {
    return A.privateShared
  }
  private static let privateShared = B()
}
```

I must clarify, this ways isn't perfect since it actually create 2 instance! So, it will technically not a `singleton` any more.

However, you can override the class B's property or method to call A.shared method or property instead. You must know what you are doing and consider use the other way to fix the problem you want to solve.