# Swift singleton subclass(inheritance)

Tags: swift, oop, design-patterns, singleton

I know the simplest way to write singleton in swift is

```
class A {
    static let shared = A()
    private init() { //... }
    func a() {}
}
// usage
A.shared.a()
```

the question is that is it possible to write a subclass singleton of class A?

I got the following code from someone to do it by class function

```
class A {
    class func shared() -> A {
        private struct _A {
            static let _shared = A()
        }
        return _A.shared
    }
    func a() { //... }
}
class B: A {
    class func shared() -> B {
        private struct _B {
            static let _shared = B()
        }
        return _B.shared
    }
    func b() { //... }
}
// usage
A.shared.a()
B.shared.b()
```

but the problem is that I can't use private init() to hide initialization here, since there is no `protected init()` to do this

Does anyone know how to subclass a singleton class by using the private init()?
thanks!

Comment: From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35865212/ios-subclass-singleton-in-swift#comment59394446_35865212: *"You never subclass a singleton. Because if you subclass it then it's not a singleton anymore"*

Comment: thanks @MartinR ! Since I just read singleton pattern from GoF Design Patterns and there was something about subclassing singleton in other language, just wondering can we do it in Swift

Comment: Why would you need to subclass a singleton? In swift it makes not really sense

Comment: @SaiLi: What are your trying to achieve? What did you read about which language?

Comment: @Kingalione just want to implement singleton inheritance from the book in swift and wonder if I can do it in swift, thx

Comment: @MartinR the book is written in Smalltalk and C++. I just want to implement a singleton class which can be inherited by others and encapsulate the initialization process. thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is a good idea to go down this road.  However, if you must, you could keep them in the same file and use fileprivate to accomplish this.

in class A declaration:

```
fileprivate init() { }
```

in class B declaration:

```
override fileprivate init() { }
```

Good luck!

Comment: but what if they are parts of different modules?